# Angular 6 select animation based on condition

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

```
<div [@SwipeRightToLeft] [@SwipeLeftToRight]>
  <a *ngIf='!(translationService.currentLanguage =="en")'>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want the to conditionally select the animation based on the `translationService.currentLanguage`, if it's `en` then use the `[@SwipeLeftToRight]` animation.

How can I do it in Angular 6?

Comment: Hey @Offir, instead of using 2 different animation, you can use one trigger with different states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do.

In your **.ts** file.

```
getCurrentLanguage()
{
   return this.translationService.currentLanguage;
}
```

as for the animation

```
animations: [
    trigger('swipe', [
      transition("void => en", [
        //swipe right
        ]
      )
    ]),
    trigger('swipe', [
      transition("void => ''", [
        //swipe left        ]
      )
    ])
  ]
})
```

and for you **HTML** file.

```
<div [@Swipe]="getCurrentLanguage()">
  <a>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!